# Fitting change of basis matrix to data

Tags: python, scipy, scipy-optimize

Taking the simple relationship:

A*X + X0 = B,

where X, X0 and B are 2*1 vector and A is a 2*2 matrix, I would like to find the best (A, X0) given a set of points (X, B).

I could not find anything that suits this problem directly in the `scipy.optimize` library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The equation could be solved using [linear least square](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.lstsq.html):

[image: equation]

where `(Ax, Ay)` are the points coordinates in the first base, `(Bx, By)` are the points coordinates in the second base. `[[a, b], [c, d]]` is the affine transformation matrix (scaling and rotation) and `[tx, ty]` is translation.

```
import numpy as np
A = np.array([[1, 3], [1, 2], [1, 1], [2, 1]])
B = np.array([[4, -2], [4, -4], [4, -6], [2, -6]])

R, residuals, rank, s = np.linalg.lstsq(np.hstack([A, np.ones((A.shape[0], 1))]), B, rcond=None)

R
#array([[-2.00000000e+00, -1.07062737e-15],
#       [ 4.44089210e-16,  2.00000000e+00],
#       [ 6.00000000e+00, -8.00000000e+00]])
```

Comment: I actually wanted to use this but it seemed to me that it was done to find the vector x in the problem Ax = b . It see the trick to add a column of ones, but I am not quite sure that I understand how it works ...

Comment: @Liris it finds x in the equation A*x = b, but x could be a matrix... it is actually two independant linear regressions, the first find the vector [a, b, tx] using [Bx0, ... Bxn] and the second finds [c, d, ty] using the data [By0, ..., Byn]

Answer (score 0):

You could rewrite your Optimization problem to

A*X + X0 - B = 0

to minimize it via `scipy.optimize.minimize()`.
`optimize()` need a scalar value as result, as you have a vector you could e.g. take the `norm()` of it.

Before you start to optimize, you need to unpack your matrix `A` and vector `X0` into separate parameters first:

```
A11, A12, A21, A22, X01, X02 = params
```

Full example:

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.optimize as optimize
from numpy import linalg as LA

def f(params):
    A11, A12, A21, A22, X01, X02 = params
    A = np.array([[A11,A12],[A21,A22]])
    X0 = np.array([[X01],[X02]])
    B = np.array([[3],[4]]) #Your Data
    X = np.array([[5],[6]]) #Your data
    return LA.norm(np.dot(A,X) + X0 - B)

initial_guess = [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
result = optimize.minimize(f, initial_guess, method='Nelder-Mead')

if result.success:
    params = result.x
    A = np.array([[params[0],params[1]],[params[2],params[3]]])
    X0 = np.array([[params[4]],[params[5]]])
    print('A:\n', A)
    print('\nX0:\n', X0)
else:
    raise ValueError(result.message)
```

```
A:
 [[ 0.6154153  -0.37465204]
 [ 1.08401302 -0.40455254]]

X0:
 [[2.17092406]
 [1.00727269]]
```

Comment: Thank, but I wanted to avoid to specify all the parameters separetely. It works perfectly though !